# Unable to compile TypeScript when import reflect-metadata

Tags: typescript

I have a script,

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

const plane = {
  color: 'red'
}

Reflect.defineMetadata('note', 'hi there', plane)
```

I set tsconfig.json,

```
/* Experimental Options */
"experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

And run `npm install reflect-metadata`

Use `ts-node` to run it but got an error,

```
# ts-node demo.ts
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:293
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
test.ts:7:9 - error TS2339: Property 'defineMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

7 Reflect.defineMetadata('note', 'hi there', plane)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:293:12)
    at reportTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:297:19)
    at getOutput (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:399:34)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:457:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:536:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:539:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
```

But I can use `tsc demo.ts` to build a demo.js and run it without an error.

Comment: Which version of `reflect-metadata` are you using?

Comment: Please add the content of `tsconfig.json` to the question. Your code works fine on my setup as `reflect-metadata` includes type definitions.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue is from tsconfig.json, the `module` should be `commonjs` or just comment out.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,      /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES2019",          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",        /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
  }
}
```

Althoudth I still don't understad the root cuase. The `tsc demo.ts` can pass with any module options but `ts-node demo.ts` can't

Answer (score -1):

Adding `reflect-metadata` to the types section of your tsconfig could help

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "reflect-metadata"    <====  THIS LINE SHOULD BE ADDED
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Having the same issue. Seems like reflect-metadata only works with commonJS modules.

edit: ok I made it work with these settings

```
tsconfig.json:
"target": "ES5"
"module": "ESNext"
"moduleResolution": "node"

package.json
"type": "module"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).